# How can I solve "Gateway disabled: PayPal Standard does not support your store currency." in WooCommerce running on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I'm working on a website using WordPress and Woocommerce Plugin, I would like to use PayPal as a Payment gateway but I get the message "Gateway disabled: PayPal Standard does not support your store currency" every time I try to set up PayPal. I am based in Kenya and the currency is (Kenyan shilling) which is not supported by PayPal. I have read many articles explaining how to solve this by adding some code on `functions.php` of my theme (even what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678751/i-have-this-error-in-woocommerce-gateway-disabled-paypal-does-not-support-your)).

I don't want to use a child theme, is there a place I can directly modify the code in WooCommerce plugin? Using the below code on my `functions.php` file did not work.

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_paypal_supported_currencies’, ‘add_paypal_valid_currency’ );
function add_paypal_valid_currency( $currencies ) {
array_push ( $currencies , ‘Ksh’ ); /* YOUR CURRENCY */
return $currencies;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use PayPal, transactions must be denominated in a supported PayPal currency, such as USD or EUR.

So, change your store store to use such a currency. Modifying the code to forcibly enable PayPal Standard even though you're using an unsupported currency will just result in checkout errors, as PayPal will reject transactions denominated in KSH.

When using a supported currency, if the payer has a funding source in some other local currency (such as KSH), the conversion will be shown to them in the PayPal checkout.

Comment: thank you for your response, the problem is that I'm also using a local payment gateway called MPESA (used in Kenya) which supports Kenya shilling and not USD on Woocommerce, so I wanted to have two Payment Gateways; MPESA and PayPal.

Comment: In that case you would need to configure your store with multiple currencies somehow, and have it show the right payment methods depending on the currency selected. WooCommerce seems to have some multi-currency support, but you may need other plugins as well https://woocommerce.com/document/payments/currencies/multi-currency-setup/